# How to catch "outside" / external buttons in app?

Tags: android

I need to find a way to catch buttons from a car stereo (like forward and backwards) inside my music player app. So that, when the next button the car stereo is pressed, it somehow correlates to my actual next button in my app. How would I go on about that?

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know the details but there should be intents for those that you can capture.

Comment: I spent hours googeling and there is NOTHING...

Comment: I am not sure if the car buttons actually send these out but I would suspect so. Take a look at MediaControlIntent: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaControlIntent